# Difference between downloading speed

Tags: networking, speed, adsl, internet-speed, adsl-router

I have ADSL connection with speed around 7.7-8 Mbsec. Monitoring traffic shows that on youtube i have all of that speed, but in other cases like torrents or game launchers i have aroud 700 - 800 Kbsec. Speed tests also shows that my speed is 7.7Mbsec. Firewall disabled, everything what can possibly block me disabled too.

What i can do with it?

Sorry for my writing, english is not my language.

Comment: What cane you do about what?  Are you sure your ISP is offering you a 8 Mb/sec connection?  The units are particularly important.

Comment: Of course, ether way how can i easily watch any video in 1080p on youtube.

Comment: Can you answer my question?  Are you sure you are using the correct units.  It matters.

Comment: Are the "torrents or game launchers" showing speed in kB/s or kb/s? There's a ~10x difference between B and b. 8 Mbps ≈ 800 kB/s ≈ 0.8 MB/s.

Comment: Sorry, misread your question. Yes the units are correct 8Mbsec and 800 Kbsec.

Comment: @user71305 - As pointed out, 8 Mb/sec is precisely the speed you are achieving, if you are downloading at 800 Kb/sec.

Comment: Your connection to any given resources is limited to the slowest link in the chain. Every server/service you connect to is over a series of networks and your overall speed is limited by whichever network is the slowest, or even the server itself. That makes comparing speeds between services like Netflix, who has the capital to pay for bandwidth, and a torrent site that doesn't, similar to comparing apples and oranges.

Answer (score 0):

The speed (throughput) you experience can vary from one Internet host (e.g. website) to the next because of how traffic moves across the Internet.

Packets sent between your computer and the remote host traverse multiple links. For example, the first link is the connection between your computer and perhaps a switch, then the next could be from the switch to your router, followed by one from the router to your ADSL modem, and so on.

If you think of these links as different size water pipes (your LAN connection would be a big one, but the one from your LAN to your ISP will be a bit smaller), and your data as the water, it becomes apparent that the throughput you experience will be determined by the slowest link between you and the remote server.

When you run a speed test, usually it finds a server that's only a few hops away from you. The idea is to reduce the number of intervening connections so that you can find out the actual throughput of your connection to your ISP. Therefore this result should represent the **maximum potential speed** at which you can connect to other hosts on the Internet.

But if you connect to a host that involves your traffic traversing a link that is slow or experiencing congestion, the speed of *that* link determines the throughput you experience when connecting to the destination host. There's nothing you can do about this (unless there's another host located somewhere else on the Internet offering the same service that you can connect to). In other words, if your connection consists of 12 "hoses" connected in serial and hose number 8 is a tiny garden hose, then no matter how large any of the other hoses might be, your connection will run as though the whole pipe is the size of that tiny garden hose.